# Images are shrinking while click on them

Tags: html, css, image

I have a simple image and I add css border 3px to the image on click , but the problem is when I click the active class is ok but the image is shrink a bit and it look like the dimension ids different,

looks like the image is zoom out a little bit but the width and height is the same

I'd like to keep the image as is even with the 3px border on active mode

```css
   li img {
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
    
     li .active img {
        border: 3px solid #01b9d1;
        border-radius: 6px;
        cursor: default;
    }
    .overview {
      width: 140px;
      height: 77px;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
      <a>
        <img class="overview" src="imgsrc">
      </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use outline-style CSS property  in place of border..
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp

Comment: thx its not working - the size of the image is the same but its looks like the image is zoom out a little bit

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-sizing: border-box` on the img element. Using `border-box` makes the width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, check [source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp).

e.g.

```
li img {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lgwnres/)

Comment: hi thx its not working - the size of the image is the same but its looks like the image is zoom out a little bit